# Ggplot - always place 'Total' bar as the farthest right bar using geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a chart that looks like the below. Problem is that I'd like the grey 'total' bar to always be on the far right hand side.

[image]

Current code is below, can anyone please amend/provide any additional code to create this effect?

```
#plot with reorder
PrevalencePlot <- ggplot(ICSTable4, aes(x = reorder(value, Area), y = value, fill = Statistical_Significance)) +
  geom_col() +  
  scale_fill_manual(values = colours)+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=errorbarlowerplot, ymax=errorbarhigherplot),
                width=.2,                    # Width of the error bars
                position=position_dodge(.9)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = valuelabel), vjust = 2.5, colour = "black")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust=1))
```

If anyone is able to help then the below data frame could be used to generate the principle I think? Thank you!

```
df <- data.frame(Area = c("Area1", "Area2", "Area3", "Area4", "Total"),
                 Value = c(1, 3, 7, 5, 4)
)
```

Comment: Could you provide some example data! `dput(ICSTable4)`.

Comment: Before plotting, run `df$Area = forcats::fct_relevel(df$Area, "Total", after = Inf)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on the minimal example data, we can make a spartanic version of the plot that addresses the question of ordering the values, and placing a selected column at the end.

```
df <- data.frame(Area = c("Area1", "Area2", "Area3", "Area4", "Total"),
                 value = c(1, 3, 7, 5, 4),
                 Statistical_Significance = c("higher", "lower", "lower", "higher", NA))
```

It's easier to create the order of the columns before plotting, as we need to create the factors based on the order of `value` and then reposition the target column ("Total").

```
df <- df %>% 
  dplyr::arrange(desc(value)) %>% #arrange by value
  dplyr::mutate(Area = forcats::as_factor(Area)) %>% # factor that defines order on x-axis
  dplyr::mutate(Area = forcats::fct_relevel(Area, "Total", after = Inf)) # reposition "Total" column


ggplot(df, aes(x = Area, y = value, fill = Statistical_Significance)) +
  geom_col() +  
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: As a side note - this also addresses [the parallel question posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71401360/r-ggplot-maintain-x-axis-labels-after-reorder)